# Permanently block distro package installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

I'm using a package provided in a PPA on Ubuntu. I use the PPA version because Debian's version is anemic to the point its effectively broken.

Today, when I went through the cycle of `apt-get update and apt=get dist-upgrade`, I was presented with:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-arm-none-eabi libnewlib-arm-none-eabi libnewlib-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-arm-none-eabi libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls
3 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 338 kB/24.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 9,572 kB disk space will be freed.
```

`dist-upgrade` is trying to install the packages that caused me the trouble in the past: `binutils-arm-none-eabi` and `gcc-arm-none-eabi`. Even a standard `upgrade` tries to install some of the same packages that caused me trouble.

I want to permanently block the distro's packages for `binutils-arm-none-eabi` and `gcc-arm-none-eabi`. How does one Permanently block a distro package, but allow a PPA that provides the same package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In APT, you "pin" packages – i.e. specify custom package preferences based on various properties.

First run `apt-cache policy` to see properties of configured repositories, and look for one that is specific to your PPA. It'll probably have something like `release n=precise` (based on the Ubuntu release it targets) or at least `origin launchpad.net` (based on the source site):

```
$ apt-cache policy | egrep -i "(ppa|arm)"
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-terry.guo-gcc-arm-embedded,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-terry.guo-gcc-arm-embedded,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
```

Then create a file `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: binutils-arm-none-eabi
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: gcc-arm-none-eabi
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 900
```

For `Pin`, use the repository property you found earlier. For the priority, choose a number that's higher than any of the regular Debian repositories.

Finally, run `apt-cache policy binutils-arm-none-eabi` – this time with the package name – to verify that the preferences are correctly applied:

```
$ apt-cache policy gcc-arm-none-eabi
gcc-arm-none-eabi:
  Installed: 4-8-2014q2-0trusty10
  Candidate: 4-8-2014q2-0trusty10
  Package pin: 4-8-2014q2-0trusty10
  Version table:
     4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6 900
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 4-8-2014q2-0trusty10 900
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

- [AptPreferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) on Debian Wiki
- [PinningHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) on Ubuntu Wiki
- [Apt-Pinning for Beginners](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much grawity. It worked flawlessly.